# how to connect android app to drupal database?

Tags: theming, mobile-tools

I have a Drupal Site with content. I now want to make an Android App. Obviously, I would like Android App to access my Drupal site database - has anyone tried this?

From what I have read (from Google), it seems that I could use something like the [phonegap](http://drupal.org/project/phonegap) module, or the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module.

Am I on the right path? Are there other modules/tools/features I should be researching?

Comment: Yes the services module is what you need, but this is a very broad question which can't be reasonably answered in its current form. Your best bet would be to install the services module, read all the available documentation, then come back to ask specific questions about things you can't get to work :)

Comment: You can read about this: <http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile>.

Comment: you may need this SDK, this SDK can connect Drupal & Android with both session and oauth1.0a which are the most popular approach right now. https://github.com/drucloud/drupalForAndroidSDK

Comment: This Drupal 8 Android SDK might be of help - [http://drupalsdk.com/](http://drupalsdk.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a module that will help in this venture, for Drupal 6.x and 7.x sites:

[DrupalGap](http://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap)

It leverages PhoneGap (Cordova), Drupal + Services + Views Datasource (Views JSON). It provides a starting point for creating multi platform (Android, iOS, etc) mobile applications for Drupal websites.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions, I am just starting off in this project. I will try the options, report back on what/how it works for me.0

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein What if I convert the drupal site into a PWA using the pwa module? What's next? Can I use drupalgap to create a mobile of my pwa drupal site?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to make a view and output data as JSON (If you only need to get data from the drupal website) . For that , this module might be handy.

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource
```

There can be other methods as well, but if you only need to read data, then above module is a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Yes You are on the right path what you can do with Phonegap  and DrupalGap module is

1) Drupal Authenticaiton 
2) Add Content (By Default Article Content Type)
3) View Articles

This are the basic functionality so far Provided By PhoneGap and DrupalGap modules

To work with this you will require following

1) JDK(6)
2) Eclipse 
3) ADT(For Developing Android apps)
4) Set your Enviornment variable from  the following links http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Open Eclipse and create new android project and paste the code provided from this link into asset directory http://code.google.com/p/drupal-phonegap/downloads/list so the final path will be assets/www/ and run as android project i better advice you to dnt use emulator instead copy apk file from your project/bin directory and run on your own android Enjoy !!!